# xStream object has no available methods

Tags: java, maven, xstream

I added xStream to my dependencies in Maven and succesfuly created an object

```
package com.example.jersey;

import com.thoughtworks.xstream.*;

import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.POST;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;

@Path("/hello")
public class GetCoords {
    private XStream xStream = new XStream();
    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public String getMessage() {
        return "Hello world!";
    }
}
```

But if I try to call any method of this object they are all unresolved symbols as if the dependency wasn't added correctly.
Here are the Maven dependancies:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.example.jersey</groupId>
    <artifactId>Restful</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-bundle</artifactId>
            <version>1.18.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.thoughtworks.xstream</groupId>
            <artifactId>xstream</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.8</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

It's my first attempt at creating a web service so a dumbed down explanation of what I'm doing wrong would be much appreciated

Edit: I have no downloaded and added xStream to the project, removing it from maven, but the problem remains.

Comment: Well, it should work. Are you using an IDE? How are you compiling? If Eclipse, have you updated the Maven project?

Comment: @Tunaki, I'm using Intellij IDEA and I told him to update automatically, so he just downloaded something when I added the dependancy.

Comment: Try cleaning and recompiling the project.

Comment: I tried Invalidating caches and rebuilding the project but nothing changed